# If $y, z \in B$ are integral over $A$ then so are $z+y$ and $zy$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, commutative-algebra, symmetric-polynomials

Let $B$ be a ring extension of $A$, a commutative ring with $1$. Suppose $y$ and $z$ in $B$ are integral over $A$.

> Prove that $z + y$ and $zy$ are integral over $A$ using elementary symmetric functions.

Since $y$ and $z$ are integral over $A$ there exist monic polynomials $f, g \in A[x]$ such that $f(y) = 0$ and $g(z) = 0$. Assume that $\deg(f) = n$ and $\deg(g) = m$. There is an extension, say $L$, of $A$ such that both $f$ and $g$ split into linear factors in $L$:
$$ 
f(x) = (x-y_1)(x-y_2)\dots (x-y_{n}) \\ 
g(x) = (x-z_1)(x-z_2)\dots (x-z_{m})
$$
where $y_1 = y$ and $z_1 = z$.

The coefficients $s_i$ of $f$ and $s'_j$ of $g$ in $L$ are symmetric polynomials in the roots $y_i$ and $z_j$ respectively.

Define two polynomials $p$ and $q$ over $L$:
\begin{align*}
p(x) &= \prod_{i=1}^{n} \prod_{j=1}^{m} (x - (y_i + z_j)) \\
q(x) &= \prod_{i=1}^{n} \prod_{j=1}^{m} (x - y_i z_j)
\end{align*}

I have a hint that the coefficients of these two polynomials can be expressed in terms of $s_i$ and $s'_j$ (Why?). Even if it is true, why does it imply that $p$ and $q$ are in $A[x]$?

Comment: $p,q\in A[x]$ since $f,g\in A[x]$.

Comment: Now let's get back to the question: the sum of roots of $p$ is nothing but $ms_1+ns_1'$. The sum of roots of $q$ is $s_1s_1'$. Can you continue from here?

Comment: @user26857 yes, thank you!